# How to analyze EFI dynamically?

Tags: malware, firmware-analysis, uefi

I'm new to reversing UEFI Malware. There is a UEFI rootkit called **MoonBounce** which I'm trying to analyze dynamically; It's an EFI driver.

I tried a tool called [***efi_dxe_emulator***](https://github.com/assafcarlsbad/efi_dxe_emulator) but it needs an NVRAM file that I don't know exactly how to get it.

[image]

Is there a better way to dynamically analyze this EFI file?